# Draw and update PictureBox

Tags: c#, image, controls

I created a simple example,to draw on image which assigned to a `Picturebox`.
I handle the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events, getting the current mouse position,and drawing a line in the end of a `MouseUp` event.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap("myImage.png");
        pictureBox1.Image = image;
    }

    Point From, To;
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        From = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, From, To);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        To = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
```

The code works,but it draws always on the first initial image, i want to draw on the updates(the new lines created on image) .

I hope my question was clear.

Thanks.

Comment: No its not clear.  That code is not drawing to the image at all but over the picturebox's location

Comment: @Plutonix what do you mean not drawing to image at all?

Comment: The `e.Graphics` passed is for the control, it is not going to add those line to the actual image. It will look like they are part of the image and that may be what you want, its not clear

Comment: @Plutonix oh..and if i would like to draw on the curent image what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this, it worked for me:

```
Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(image);
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
{
    graph.DrawLine(Pens.Red, From.X, From.Y, e.X, e.Y);
    pictureBox1.Image = image;
}
```

Additionally, I'd recommend you use the `MouseMove` event, to make lines more smooth (don't really know if thats what you want, but anyway) like this:

```
    int x, y;

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        x = e.X;
        y = e.Y;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(image);
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            graph.DrawLine(Pens.Red, x, y, e.X, e.Y);
            pictureBox1.Image = image;
            x = e.X;
            y = e.Y;
        }
    }
```

hope I could help you :D